# Quick doubt on a Calculus problem

Tags: calculus, optimization

The problem is as follows:

> The speed at which a signal istransmitted along a cable on the bottom
>   of the ocean is proportional to $f(x)=x^2\ln(\frac{l}{x})$, where $x$ is the ratio of the radius of the core of the cable to the radius of the entire cable. What
>   value of $x$ maximizes the speed of transmission?

I know I have to find the value of $x$ that maximizes the above function. However, $f$ never attains a maximum since it blows up to infinity as $x\rightarrow\infty$. I suspect $x$ being "the ratio of the radius of the core of the cable to the radius of the entire cable" provides the needed information to determine the interval in which I should find its maximum, but I can't seem to figure it out. What am I missing out here? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Doesn't the speed blow up to -infinity as x goes to infinity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have $$f(x)=x^2\ln\left(\frac{l}{x}\right)$$ then we get $$f'(x)=2x\ln\left(\frac{l}{x}\right)-x$$
can you solve $$f'(x)=0$$?

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is that $f\to -\infty$ as $x\to +\infty$. It may help to rewrite the logarithm as $-\ln\frac{x}{l}$.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this requires us to find the roots of $f’(x)$ and check the sign of $f’’(x)$ for those values. If the sign is positive, then we take it to be a maxima. Let us proceed in this direction.

We have $$f’(x)=0 \implies 2x\ln(\frac{l}{x})+x^2\frac{x}{l}\frac{-l}{x^2}=0$$ $$\implies 2x\ln(\frac{l}{x})=x \implies x=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}l$$ dismissing the trivial solution $x=0$.

We can easily check that $f’’(x)$ is positive. Hence, $$f(x)_{\text{ max }}=\frac{l^2}{e}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{l^2e^{-1}}{2}$$